# How to make test discovery work in VSCode in multi-root workspace?

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pytest, fastapi

I have the following folder structure in python:

```
├──project1
│       ──venv
│       ──src
|           ─main.py
│       ──test
|           ─test.py
├──project2
│       ──venv
│       ──src
|           ─main.py
│       ──test
|           ─test.py
├──shared
│       ──shared-library-1
|           ─spam.py
│       ──shared-library-2
|           ─very-common.py
|
```

Project1 & project2 are FastAPI services with their own virtual environments, dependencies, tests and they have some shared code too in the shared folder. I've created a multi-root VS Code code workspace to have all this under one umbrella, so I can run and debug both service at the some time conveniently. It works nicely for running and debugging the projects, but I'm having issues with setting up testing.

I can create launch configurations to run all pytests from terminal, but the built-in VS Code test discovery fails with error (on test.py):

**"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'"**

I think I know why, it's the classic import error because python can't import main.py from test.py unless pythonpath environment variable is not set up correctly. This is the launch configuration to run tests for project1:

```
{
            "name": "Project1 Tests",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "module": "pytest",
            "python":"${workspaceRoot:project1}/venv/bin/python",
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder:project1}",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder:project1}/..${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"},
            "jinja": true,
            "justMyCode": true
}
```

This sets up the pythonpath nicely for each of the projects so imports can work and I can run my tests. How can I do the same for the built-in VS Code discoverer?
I'd like my tests to show up nicely in the testing tab to be able run and debug them one-by-one.

Comment: I have recently encountered similar issues with .env files, but currently the developers have not given me a response. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21371

Comment: Thanks for the info! I also tried it with .env files but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there is indeed a problem with the new version of Python extension and vscode.

I tried the old version of **1.76.0 and 1.78.2 VSCode** and **2023.2.0 Python**. It works.

I also tried the pre-release **v2023.9.11461009** version of Python. It works as well.

You can try to use pre-release version.